# preparedStatement SQL error in java when trying to insert files

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, jdbc, inputstream

[image]

Hello i get  an SQL error when trying to insert a file in the database using mediumBlob function

Comment: please post the relevant code in this question. not an image.

Comment: add your  work code  you have done for this.

Comment: no not the image... the text of your code :)

Comment: And what error might this be...?

Comment: Please post the code as **text** and the stacktrace of the exception you get.

Comment: @StefanBeike always consider to vote to close, the que is large... You are always welcome to pass by in the [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) chat

Answer (score 2):

change:

```
stm.setInt(6,taille);
```

to

```
stm.setInt(5,taille);
```

Answer (score 0):

Some error there...

First as @stefanbeike pointed out your argument numbering is off.

Second (and worse) you code the literal String  `'now()'` instead of function `now()` - and `'now()'` cannot be parsed into any meaningful date.